# iOS simulator is not lisiting in visual studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio-code, ios-simulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P4PoX.png)

iOS-simulator is not listed all the time. sometime its showing most of the time its not there. not doing any specific changes in my machine. Simply when i restart VS app. its missing.

1. tried unload & reload the ios project. still the same.
2. complete reinstall visual studio & xcode from scratch.
3. tried update xcode.

Nothing helped from above suggestions.

Would be really great help if someone could help me with this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered the same problem several times and here are some of my suggestions:

1. Did you try switching to your Android project then switch back to iOS project? This should be the simplest way
2. In your iOS project options, create a build configuration specifically dedicated to iOS Simulators only. Make sure to set *Linker behavior* to **Don't Link**
3. Quit Xcode and Visual Studio first. Open Finder, press Command + Shift + G, paste the following path: **Users/*YourUserNameHere*/Library/Developer/Devices/** You'll see a bunch of folders with encoded folder names and a file *device_set.plist*

- Next delete all the folders in Devices directory, then open device_set.plist by double clicking it. This should open it in Xcode. You'll see a bunch of key-value pairs under DefaultDevices and DevicePairs, click on the arrow on the left side and delete of the devices listed there by hovering the mouse over a category and click the minus (-) button next to it.
- Press Command + Shift + 2 to open Devices & Simulators Window (Alternatively you can choose on menu Window -> Devices and Simulators. Choose Simulators on the left sidebar. Delete all the simulators if there's still any of them showing up. Then create several simulators, ones that you really need for debugging your app. Quit Xcode, reboot the machine, open Visual Studio again.

Comment: Thanks @HungXtran  - I already tired point 1 and it didn't help me. Tried the step 3 and it helped me. THanks alot

Comment: @PRASATHKUMARPONNUSWAMY I'm a newbie here so it'd be great if you give me a vote up and/or marked answered. Thanks!